# How to get the procedure's call stack in code

Tags: delphi, stack, procedure

I'm using Delphi 5. I want to get in code, all the calling procedure's call stack. For example:

> procedure main (line 17) > function F1 (line 34) > function F2 (line 2)

MadExcept does exactly that, but only when it handles an exception. I want to get it when I'm asking. I need it for a log.

Is there a way to get that infomation, by MadExcept, or by another way?

Comment: What doesn't work with function StackTrace from madStackTrace.pas? Of course you need to parse the result and construct the format you desire.

Comment: with EurekaLog you can do it. See [get the call stack from eurekalog at any time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305666/get-the-call-stack-from-eurekalog-at-any-time)

Comment: You can do this from madExcept, just search or ask on the forum

Comment: [Call Stack](http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=28705) and [Get stack trace quickly](http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=28259) and [Get StackTrace for Exception](http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=28374) sound promising.

Answer (score -2):

What I remember from my old Delphi 5 days is that [MemCheck](http://v.mahon.free.fr/pro/freeware/memcheck/) also is able to read the call stack from within a procedure call. It may require to set very specific compiler and linker options in the project properties.